# aws s3 cp multipart retry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am attempting to upload a file (567GB) to Amazon AWS S3. It has failed twice. AWS S3 now has a 5TB limit. I already uploaded about 10 files. Here is the command I am running:

aws s3 cp D:\OVA\myvm.ova s3://my_bucket/myvm.ova

Here is the message I am getting:

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myvm.ova?partNumber=4518&uploadId=abc123xyzabc123xyzabc123xyzabc123xyzabc123xyzabc123xyz"
upload failed: D:\OVA\myvm.ova to s3://my_bucket/myvm.ova

Can someone tell me how to resume or restart the upload from where the error occured? Is there a way of doing so using the partNumber?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/737507/how-to-upload-a-large-file-using-aws-commandline-when-connection-may-be-unreliab

Comment: Where does it show I am using the GET method? I'm uploading a file to S3, not downloading.